# Ruby on Rails adding PDFs to partials

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf

I have a rails form that a user fills out, and later they can print it off as a PDF. The content is very similar (removed navbar and links, etc).

Now I need to add PDF documents at specific locations of the PDF version of the form.

For example, take a form for a rental application that has the property details, first tenant details, pdf document, followed by a second tenants details, another pdf document.

I'm currently using PDFkit to generate PDFs from html. But I'm open to suggestions.

Thanks,

Comment: I don't understand, do you want separate PDFs for each of those form submissions, or all of the form submissions to be combined into one PDF? What does "at specific locations" mean?

Comment: I want the generated form(s) and existing PDFs to be joined into 1 PDF. "At specific locations" I mean the PDFs I want to add need to be inserted into the document at/after specific pages. I.e. The first PDF in my example is after the page that has the first tenant details.